# GAE Endpoint Security testing with local dev envrionment

Tags: google-app-engine

I am trying to secure my GAE service endpoints. So I added the following annotations to my service class and deploy this service to GAE:

@Api(name="mytestapi",version="v2", description="An API for testing" ,
    scopes = {Constants.EMAIL_SCOPE},
    clientIds = {Constants.WEB_CLIENT_ID,  Constants.ANDROID_CLIENT_ID,   Constants.API_EXPLORER_CLIENT_ID},
    audiences = {Constants.ANDROID_AUDIENCE})

When I try to access my service with the API explorer at the Google Development Server everything works fine. I receive the answer that the User is authorized but when I try to access this service from my local machine I just receive the message that the user is not authorized

```
    GET http://localhost:8888/_ah/api/mytestapi/v2/ .....

    Authorization:  Bearer ya29.1.AADtN_X_Uku4qj0ehwOwRqLLmKvbIOOYOCC2KXOnVskUXT7Yy19bNsiIGepXTzI
    X-JavaScript-User-Agent:  Google APIs Explorer



401 Unauthorized

- Show headers -

{
"error": {
"message": "User is Not Valid",
"code": 401,
"errors": [
{
"domain": "global",
"reason": "required",
"message": "User is Not Valid"
}
]
}
}
```

Any Idea what I have missed to configure or what I am doing wrong?

Regards

Michael

Answer (score 0):

In the credentials of your application, on the [console](https://console.developers.google.com) Google, you have to add the localhost origin in the Javascript Origins, section Client ID for web application.

Comment: hi, I added the following two entries: https://localhost:8888
http://localhost:8888 but it still does not work

Comment: Remove the port, I don't put it in my case.

Comment: sorry, no success. it still returns the error that the user is not authorized. I followed these steps http://rominirani.com/2014/02/14/google-cloud-endpoints-tutorial-part-5/

Comment: ok, its working now after I updated my dev environment from 1.9.2 to 1.9.4. So my confiugration were fine